# How do I pass data from one VC to another using closures in swift instead of delegates?

Tags: ios, swift, closures

I have two VCs currently, one that displays a counter UILabel and another that displays a button, pressing which is supposed to increment the UILabel on the original VC by one.

I'm still learning Swift, and I know how to solve this issue using delegates, but want to learn how to do so using closures, which I'm finding a little difficult to do without seeing an example; hence the bountied question.

Here is my first VC with the UILabel counter:

```
var tappedCount: Int = 10

lazy var label: UILabel = {
    let label = UILabel()
    label.text = "\(tappedCount)"
    label.textAlignment = .center
    label.font = UIFont(name: "Copperplate", size: 90)
    label.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = false
    return label
}()

override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()
    view.backgroundColor = .white
    navigationItem.title = "Navigation Controller"
    navigationController?.navigationBar.isTranslucent = false
    view.addSubview(label)
    view.addSubview(button)

    let nextButton = UIBarButtonItem(barButtonSystemItem: .add, target: self, action: #selector(moveToSecond))
    navigationItem.rightBarButtonItem = nextButton

    label.centerXAnchor.constraint(equalTo: view.centerXAnchor).isActive = true
    label.centerYAnchor.constraint(equalTo: view.centerYAnchor).isActive = true
  }

@objc func moveToSecond() {
    show(SecondViewController(), sender: self)
}
```

and here is my second VC with the button:

```
class SecondViewController: UIViewController {

    var callback : (() -> Void)?

    @objc func buttonPressed() {
        print("hello")
    }

    let button: UIButton = {
        let button = UIButton()
        button.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = false
        button.addTarget(self, action: #selector(buttonPressed), for: .touchUpInside)
        button.setTitle("HELLO", for: .normal)
        button.backgroundColor = .red
        return button
    }()

    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()
        view.backgroundColor = .white
        view.addSubview(button)

        button.centerXAnchor.constraint(equalTo: view.centerXAnchor).isActive = true
        button.centerYAnchor.constraint(equalTo: view.centerYAnchor).isActive = true
        button.heightAnchor.constraint(equalToConstant: 100).isActive = true
        button.widthAnchor.constraint(equalToConstant: 100).isActive = true

           }
    }
```

Comment: I am sorry if this is off for this website, but I don't think this issue I will be able to solve my myself. Can you explain a little more clearly what I am to do?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You have to assign the closure in the first view controller and call it in the second

change `moveToSecond` to

```
@objc func moveToSecond(_ sender : UIBarButtonItem) {
    let secondViewController = SecondViewController()
    secondViewController.callback = {
       self.tappedCount += 1
       self.label.text = Sting(self.tappedCount)
    }
    show(secondViewController, sender: self)
}
```

and `buttonPressed` to

```
@objc func buttonPressed(_ sender : UIButton) {
    callback?()
}
```

It's good practice to pass the affected UI element as `sender` in the `action`.

Comment: I've marked the answer as accepted, but there is no notification that tells me if you've been awarded the bounty as yet or not. Please let me know if I'm supposed to do something specific to make that happen. Thank you !